# Suspend Change event of ExtJS combo when we type to search item

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, combobox, onchange

I am trying to override **initComponent** of combo to make changes required to enable search in combo . I have done this using following code...

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.ComboBox, {
            initComponent: function() {
                var me = this;
                if(!me.hideTrigger && !me.multiSelect){                     
                    me.editable = true;
                    me.forceSelection = true;
                    me.queryMode = 'local';
                }
                me.callParent(arguments);
            }

        });
```

I have achieved what I want by this code. But problem is when I start typing in combo to search item in it , combo 'change' event is fired on every keypress.
I want 'change 'event to fire only when user selects item . Also I don't want use 'select' event as this will require me to convert all used 'change' events to 'select'. So is there a solution which will prevent firing 'change' event when I am searching in combo items using keyboard.

May be something we can do using **suspendcheckchange** ,**beforeQuery** or **afterQuery**

http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/LTVXF/

Comment: The solution is to use the `select` event, that's what it's there for. Trying to work around it in a hacky way will just lead to more problems.